# Programmatically bind the width of a node object to the width property of a TabPane

Tags: javafx

everyone.

I have the following problem: I have a method `addToTabPane(Node node)`. Within this method, the `Node` object is inserted into a `Tab` and the tab is added to a `TabPane`. This works perfectly well.

I now want each passed `Node` object to be bound to the `widthProperty` of the `TabPane`.

How can I do this if `addToTabPane()` gets a `Node` object passed?

Comment: If you use the proper parent you don't need to use a binding. `TabPane` resizes the content of a tab...

Comment: By default, the content of a tab will fill the tab pane when selected, if its resizable range allows it to. So there is no need to use bindings, just ensure the node you pass can grow to an arbitrary size.

Comment: Okay, okay, okay. I forgot to mention one little thing: The `TabPane` is located within a `SplitPane` and the content should also react when the SplitPane Divider is changed.

That's why I thought of binding.

Comment: Again, that should happen by default.

Comment: I've tried it, and it actually works. It does not work only if the `Node` object is a `ScrollPane`.

Comment: Works for me, even with a scroll pane.

Comment: Then I need to look, why it does not work for me. The content within the `ScrollPane` is not growing. Thanks so far.